# How can we use variable inside a quote in Python?

Tags: python, terraform

I took a template file in terraform and I want to pass that variable in python, but throws an error each time I use.

```
      {
           'Name': 'tag:Name',
           'Values': [value]
        },
```

I want to pass the variable using this filter. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: SO isn't a software development service. Please update your answer with more details around what you have tried and what errors you receive for others to help you out.

Comment: Please add the exact steps you are taking and the error message you are getting and also define *“passing a variable”* and *“filter”*. If you want to expand (print) a variable into a string, search for f-strings.

Comment: why not set `value = 'somestring'` and then `'Values': value`

Answer (score 3):

you add the letter f before quotes and then use {} to display variables

```
i = 5
print(f"something {i}")
```

output: **something 5**